# How to handle button states efficiently in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, state

I've done a few searches but I couldn't find anything about this topic. Perhaps because it is common programmer knowledge (I'm not a programmer, I've learned from necessity), or because I'm going about it the wrong way.

I would like ideas/suggestions on how to manage button states for a GUI. For example, if I have a program which allows the user to import and process data, then certain functions should be inaccessible until the data has been imported successfully, or if they want to graph certain data, they need to select which data to graph before hitting the 'graph' or 'export' button. Even in the simple programs I've built these relationships seems to get complicated quickly. It seems simple to say "User shouldn't be able to hit button 'A' until 'B' and 'C' have been completed, then 'A' should be disabled if button 'D' or the 'Cancel' button. But that's a lot to track for one button. Thus far, I've tried two things:

- Changing/Checking button states in the callback functions for the button. So in the above example, I would have code in buttons B's and C's callback to check if A should be enabled. And in buttons D's and Cancel's callbacks I would have code to disable button A. This gets complicated quickly and is difficult to maintain as code changes.
- Setting boolean variables in every buttons callback (or just checking the states later using cget()) and checking the variables in a polling function to determine which buttons should be enabled or disabled.

I'm just not sure about this. I would like to make code as short and easy to understand as possible (and easy to edit later), but I don't like the idea of polling all the button states every few hundred milliseconds just for button 'management'. You can extend the same idea to check boxes, menu items, etc... but I'd like to here what others have done and why they do it the way they do.

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing button states based on events, right? There is no reason to 'poll' to see if a button state has changed.  What you can do is build a function which does all of the calling for you, then call it with something like `disable_buttons([okButton, graphButton, printButton])`. When an event takes place that modifies the appropriate user interface options (such as importing data), have another function that turns them on: `enable_buttons([graphButton])`.  You could do this with each object's methods, of course, but making a wrapper allows you to be consistent throughout your application.